первый бот aiogram ошибка импорта
при запуске файла терминал пишет No module named 'aiogram'
ы проблемах к коду написано 'не удалось импортировать aiogram'
Но в терминале я прописал pip install aiogram.
И в pip list я вижу, что aiogram установлен
версия пайтон 3.11
версия aiogram 3.7.0
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart

API_TOKEN = '1234'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message_handler(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Hello! I am your bot.")
    await message.reply("How are you doing?")

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


думаю стоит сначала изучить питон и как работает венв, а потом уже писать ботов
